# encryption using C++ (errors reading ciphertext)

Tags: c++, encryption

this is the first time I use this forum and I did it out of pure desperation. I am supposed to write an encryption program that utilizes Des algorythm. I managed to write the Des code perfectly well and it works without any errors from the memory. But my trouble starts when I have to read the ciphertext from a file and then decrypt it. It works sometimes and others not. I tried so many ways to work around the problem but reached no where. Here is the code of the main without the Des code itself. Please help me

```
int main()
{
    Des d1,d2;
    char *str=new char[1000];
    char *str1=new char[1000];
    char c;

    ifstream *keyFile;
    ofstream cipherFile ;

    keyFile= new ifstream;
    keyFile->open ( "key.txt", ifstream::binary) ;
    binaryToHexa (keyFile);
    cipherFile.open ( "ciphertext.dat", ofstream::binary) ;
    std::ifstream plainFile("plaintext.txt", ifstream::binary);

    plainFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::ifstream::pos_type filesize = plainFile.tellg();
    plainFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> bytes(filesize);

    plainFile.read(&bytes[0], filesize);

    str = new char[bytes.size() + 1]; // +1 for the final 0
    str[bytes.size() + 1] = '\0'; // terminate the string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size(); ++i)
    {
        str[i] = bytes[i];
    }

    char *temp=new char[9];
    for(int i=0; i<filesize; i+=8)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            temp[j]=str[i+j];
        }
        temp[8]='\0';
        str1=d1.Encrypt(temp);
        cipherFile<<str1;
        //cout<<d2.Decrypt(str1);
    }
    cipherFile.close();
    plainFile.close();

    std::ifstream cipherFileInput("ciphertext.dat", std::ios::binary);

    cipherFileInput.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::ifstream::pos_type filesize2 = cipherFileInput.tellg();
    cipherFileInput.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<char> bytes2(filesize2);

    char* res;

    cipherFileInput.read(&bytes2[0], filesize2);

    res = new char[bytes2.size() + 1]; // +1 for the final 0
    res[bytes2.size() + 1] = '\0'; // terminate the string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes2.size(); ++i)
    {
        res[i] = bytes2[i];
    }

    char *temp2=new char[9];
    for(int i=0; i<filesize2; i+=8)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            temp2[j]=res[i+j];
        }
        temp2[8]='\0';
        str1=d2.Decrypt(temp2);
        cout<<str1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Does it crash?  Does it give an error message?  Does it give erroneous results?  Have you tried stepping through your program with a debugger to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch as you gave little information about the problem your file may have control chars in it like carriage returns, line feeds, etc that you didn't encounter with your in memory test.

Comment: Why are you allocating things with `new`?

Comment: sry for not elaborating on the error. I do not get a specific error, just rubbish characters instead of the decrypted text. I do have the same hunch about the control chars as the filesize is always 2 characters longer than it supposed to be. How to fix that?

Comment: out of my desperation I started to reallocated variables with new thinking maybe its the one causing the errors. I understand now its not needed.

Comment: I notice that you output the encrypted text using the formatted output operator : `cipherFile<<str1`. Does `d1.Encrypt` guarantee that there will be a nul byte at the end of its returned array, and that there won't be a nul byte anywhere in the middle? If not, consider `cipherFile.write()`.

Comment: If it works in memory but not when files are involved, then the flaw must lie in either the file reading or file writing code. Try testing each separately.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem, but you have at least two undefined behaviors in your program. You write one byte beyond the allocation for `str` and for `res`:

```
    str = new char[bytes.size() + 1]; // +1 for the final 0
    str[bytes.size() + 1] = '\0'; // terminate the string
    ...
    res = new char[bytes2.size() + 1]; // +1 for the final 0
    res[bytes2.size() + 1] = '\0'; // terminate the string
```

Those assignments should be:

```
str[bytes.size()] = 0;
```

and

```
res[bytes2.size()] = 0;
```

Comment: thank you for helping but this had no effect whatsoever on the output. I still get rubbish characters.